# Hop size in STFT

Tags: python, stft

I am reading the documentation of [scipy.signal.stft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#scipy.signal.stft) function. My question: is the 'noverlap' parameter of this function equivalent with STFT hop size?

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/is-windowed-fourier-transform-a-synonym-for-stft/45631#45631) for a reasonably complete description of STFT and how FFT size, overlap %, and Hop size are all related.

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13856/filter-size-vs-fft-size-and-overlap-add/70838#70838) might also be useful, if you're using a rectangular window and doing fast convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hop size $M$ is the number of samples between each successive FFT. The 'noverlap' parameter is the number of samples $n$ to overlap between segments (and will default to $N/2$ where $N$ is the FFT frame size). The relationship between hop size, frame size and overlap is:

$M$ = $N - n$

If there is no overlap then this would simply be the total number of samples in the FFT frame.  In certain uses the overlap is given as an "Overlap Factor", where a factor of 2 would refer to a 50% overlap (stated here in case that was a source of the OP's confusion; 'noverlap' is clearly stated in the documentation as the number of samples and does not represent "overlap factor").

Answer (score 1):

For those ending up here, as stated in 'Notes' at [the official SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html):

> hop size = nperseg - noverlap